# Installing a .NET framework on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I just switched to windows 7 from Vista and a lot of programs/games don't work anymore.

The issue is that some games need a specific .NET framework version. when I try to install that it says that I should turn on/off windows features. I go to that and I find .NET framework in the list and tried both checking it and unchecking it.  Both don't work and I still get the message that I need to turn on/off that thing.

Any suggestion please?

I have Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit.

Comment: Which programs/games are you trying to install and which version of .NET do they say you need?

Comment: Possibly related: ".NET 2.0 “not installed” after upgrade to Windows 7" - http://superuser.com/questions/39599/net-2-0-not-installed-after-upgrade-to-windows-7

Comment: Good link @techie007. I'd go with the .NET Framework Cleanup Tool suggested in that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading and installing the [.Net Framework 4 Client Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=E5AD0459-CBCC-4B4F-97B6-FB17111CF544&displaylang=en). This is a small size install of the latest version of the framework, with only the core libraries needed to run most applications. The framework does a good job at being reverse compatible.